# Jquery detect if scroll is on the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, scroll

I have a code to detect user scroll, it works when scrolling bottom

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   } 
});
</script>

<div style="height: 4000px">Scroll down!</div>
```

I would like to make it works when scroll to the top of the page, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [`scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) value to see if it equals zero:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      alert("bottom!");
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
      alert("top!");
    }
  });
</script>

<div style="height: 4000px">Scroll down!</div>
```

As the scrollTop() docs state:

> If the scroll bar is at the very top, or if the element is not
>   scrollable, this number will be 0.

Comment: Great, Thank you!

Comment: should it  also work on a div `overflow-y: scroll;` should I change the `$(window).scroll(function() {` to the div id or it will work any way?